# Android Quickblox Chat - Get users facebook friends?

Tags: android, quickblox

I want to use QuickBlox chat module in my app. When the user logs in to the chat module, i want to display their FB friends from which they can select whom to chat with. I read the docs but could not find this. Can someone please help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of users authentication: standard login and password and Facebook/Twitter authentication. Depending on this you need to use appropriate password for XMPP connection: either the same password or session token.
 Please check out `[this](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Password) .'
In other words since you are using social provider for authentication your password will be equal to QB session token. For example:

```
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.ID = 298;
user.password = [BaseService sharedService].token;
[[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];
```